# Avoid The PIN step in ROAuth handshake if I'm the only user?

Tags: r, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, roauth

**Question**: Is there a way to avoid having to manually enter a PIN when doing an OAuth handshake?

**Context**: When making a ROAuth handshake, I am asked to enter a PIN which I obtain by following a link:

```
rm(list=ls())
library("twitteR")
library("ROAuth")

Credentials <- OAuthFactory$new(
  consumerKey = "...",
  consumerSecret = "...",
  oauthKey = "...",
  oauthSecret = "...",
  requestURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
  authURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize",
  accessURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token")

Credentials$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))
```

Which outputs:

> Credentials$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem",
>   package = "RCurl")) To enable the connection, please direct your web
>   browser to:  https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=...
>   When complete, record the PIN given to you and provide it here:

And I enter a PIN.

I would like to avoid this step because everytime I run the script in a new R session I have to manually open the browser to retrieve the PIN. I am the only person using this script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you perform the handshake you can save the object to a file ...

```
save(Credentials, file="credentials.RData")
```

At a later date you can use load() to pull the file in and use your original Credentials object.